# What is the purpose of MAP_ANONYMOUS flag in mmap system call?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, system-calls, mmap

From the `man` page,

```
MAP_ANONYMOUS
              The mapping is not backed by any file; its contents are initialized to zero.  The fd and offset arguments are ignored; however, some implementations  require
              fd  to  be  -1  if  MAP_ANONYMOUS  (or  MAP_ANON)  is  specified, and portable applications should ensure this.  The use of MAP_ANONYMOUS in conjunction with
              MAP_SHARED is only supported on Linux since kernel 2.4.
```

What is the purpose of using `MAP_ANONYMOUS`? Any example would be good. Also From where the memory will be mapped?

It is written on `man` page that `The use of MAP_ANONYMOUS in conjunction with MAP_SHARED is only supported on Linux since kernel 2.4.`
How can i share the memory mapped with MAP_ANONYMOUS with other process?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Anonymous mappings can be pictured as a zeroized virtual file.
Anonymous mappings are simply large, zero-filled blocks of memory ready for use.
These mappings reside outside of the heap, thus do not contribute to data segment fragmentation.

**MAP_ANONYMOUS + MAP_PRIVATE:**

- every call creates a distinct mapping
- children inherit parent's mappings
- childrens' writes on the inherited mapping are catered in copy-on-write manner
- the main purpose of using this kind of mapping is to allocate a new zeroized memory
- malloc employs anonymous private mappings to serve memory allocation requests larger than MMAP_THRESHOLD bytes.
        typically, MMAP_THRESHOLD is 128kB.

**MAP_ANONYMOUS + MAP_SHARED:**

- each call creates a distinct mapping that doesn't share pages with any other mapping
- children inherit parent's mappings
- **no copy-on-write** when someone else sharing the mapping writes on the shared mapping
- shared anonymous mappings allow IPC in a manner similar to System V memory segments, but only between related processes

On Linux, there are two ways to create anonymous mappings:

- specify MAP_ANONYMOUS flag and pass -1 for fd

  ```
      addr = mmap(NULL, length, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0); 
      if (addr == MAP_FAILED)
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  ```
- open /dev/zero and pass this opened fd

  ```
      fd = open("/dev/zero", O_RDWR);   
      addr = mmap(NULL, length, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
  ```

  (this method is typically used on systems like BSD, that do not have MAP_ANONYMOUS flag)

**Advantages of anonymous mappings:**
 - no virtual address space fragmentation; after unmapping, the memory is immediately returned to the system
 - they are modifiable in terms of allocation size, permissions and they can also receive advice just like normal mappings
 - each allocation is a distinct mapping, separate from global heap

**Disadvantages of anonymous mappings:**
 - size of each mapping is an integer multiple of system's page size, thus it can lead to wastage of address space
 - creating and returning mappings incur more overhead than that of from the pre-allocated heap

if a program containing such mapping, forks a process, the child inherits the mapping.
The following program demonstrates this kinda inheritance:

```C
#ifdef USE_MAP_ANON
#define _BSD_SOURCE
#endif  
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /*Pointer to shared memory region*/    
    int *addr;   

#ifdef USE_MAP_ANON      /*Use MAP_ANONYMOUS*/           
     addr = mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);     
     if (addr == MAP_FAILED) {     
         fprintf(stderr, "mmap() failed\n");     
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }      

#else        /*Map /dev/zero*/     
    int fd;    
    fd = open("/dev/zero", O_RDWR);      
    if (fd == -1) {    
        fprintf(stderr, "open() failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }    

    addr = mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);    
    if (addr == MAP_FAILED) {    
        fprintf(stderr, "mmap() failed\n");    
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);    
    }     

    if (close(fd) == -1) {          /*No longer needed*/    
        fprintf(stderr, "close() failed\n");    
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);    
    }
#endif    
    *addr = 1;      /*Initialize integer in mapped region*/    

    switch(fork()) {        /*Parent and child share mapping*/     
    case -1:    
        fprintf(stderr, "fork() failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);    

    case 0:         /*Child: increment shared integer and exit*/     
        printf("Child started, value = %d\n", *addr);    
        (*addr)++;    

        if (munmap(addr, sizeof(int)) == -1) {    
            fprintf(stderr, "munmap()() failed\n");    
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);    
        }     
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);     

    default:        /*Parent: wait for child to terminate*/      
        if (wait(NULL) == -1) {    
            fprintf(stderr, "wait() failed\n");    
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);      
        }     

        printf("In parent, value = %d\n", *addr);         
        if (munmap(addr, sizeof(int)) == -1) {       
            fprintf(stderr, "munmap()() failed\n");      
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);       
        }        
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**Sources:**
    The Linux Programming Interface
    Chapter 49: Memory Mappings,
    Author: Michael Kerrisk

Linux System Programming (3rd edition)
Chapter 8: Memory Management,
Author: Robert Love

Comment: hi @nachiketkulk, Does MAP_ANONYMOUS means contiguous virtual memory  ?

Comment: @ransh: `mmap` always creates a single contiguous mapping of virtual addresses so you can use it as an array.  The underlying physical pages don't have to be contiguous or in any particular order, as usual with virtual memory.

Comment: `mmap` can merge new mappings with compatible mappings with the result that `munmap` returns ENOMEM if unmapping would result in the limit of mapping being exceeded.

Comment: In the example program, I cannot see any reason to `munmap` it twice(both in child and parent process).

Comment: @PeterCordes *"These mappings reside outside of the heap, thus do not contribute to data segment fragmentation."* But how does heap contribute to data segment fragmentation? In Linux these are two different segments..

Comment: @NK-cell:  "The heap" isn't a real thing anyway, so that phrase in the answer isn't very clear.  Perhaps it's talking about space allocated with `brk`?  (Which can only be safely handed back to the OS by moving the break to a lower address if *all* intervening allocations have been freed).  So sure, using brk (like a reverse stack doing LIFO allocations) means fragmentation of those allocations can be a problem (large free-list you can't give back to the OS), and the break is normally at the end of the data segment (i.e. after the BSS).

Comment: This answer's terminology in the opening paragraph is only helpful for people that already understand the details of what actually happens, if that's what it was even intended to mean.  But yes, being able to give the memory back to the OS right away on `free` is why glibc `malloc` uses `mmap` for large allocations, even on systems where it uses brk for small allocations.

Comment: @PeterCordes So knowing that the glibc's `malloc()` has such a fork (`brk` for small allocations vs `mmap` for the large ones) we can just do `malloc()` assuming that there is nothing more to optimize here? I.e. knowing this we don't need to use anon `mmap` explicitly?

Comment: @NK-cell: glibc malloc is not the fastest implementation, I think.  Some replacement libraries are commonly used.  And it's always possible for it to do poorly with huge amounts of small allocations.  Usually it's good enough, and if not you should look for another existing malloc implementation, though.  I guess it could make sense to manually use mmap in a specific place if you always want page alignment, and you always still know the size when you're going to free (so you don't need any extra bookkeeping metadata), and the allocation is always large and used for a long time.

Comment: If you just need to reserve some RAM, `malloc()` is the correct way to proceed. Specialized allocation routine is needed if `malloc()` performance is not good enough (and with modern Linux libc it's pretty fast already!) and you want anonymous `mmap()` in case you need to share RAM segment between processes or need explicit point in code to free the memory back to OS. Note that you have to touch every page in anonymous `mmap` to force real allocation of RAM, otherwise it's just virtual memory address space segment not backed up by actual RAM.

Comment: There is still a use case for `mmap` over `malloc`, namely the ability to set the MAP flags such as `MAP_POPULATE` which ensures the entire area has been pre-faulted so that it's available for use, and then calling `mlock` to prevent it ever being swapped to disk. This can be very useful for applications that need to ensure that the ram latency never jumps due to having to fault it back in, IE, audio buffers for real time playback.