# Difference between `multiprocessing.shared_memory` and anonymous mmap?

Tags: python, shared-memory, mmap

What is the technical difference between multiprocessing SharedMemory and an anonymous mmap? Is one better than the other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of MAP\_ANONYMOUS flag in mmap system call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34042915/what-is-the-purpose-of-map-anonymous-flag-in-mmap-system-call)

Comment: @Jemshit No, this is just about anonymous mmap on linux in general, but I'm interested in a python viewpoint and the comparison with multiprocessing posix shared memory specifically.