# How to easily diagnose problems due to access to unmapped mmap regions?

Tags: linux, debugging, valgrind, mmap, address-sanitizer

I've recently found a segfault that neither Valgrind, nor Address Sanitizer could give any useful info about. It happened because the faulty program `munmap`ped a file and then tried to access the formerly `mmap`ped region.

The following example demonstrates the problem:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main()
{
    const int fd=open("/tmp/test.txt", O_RDWR);
    if(fd<0) abort();
    const char buf[]="Hello";
    if(write(fd, buf, sizeof buf) != sizeof buf) abort();

    char*const volatile ptr=mmap(NULL,sizeof buf,PROT_READ,MAP_SHARED,fd,0);
    if(!ptr) abort();
    printf("1%c\n", ptr[0]);

    if(close(fd)<0) abort();
    printf("2%c\n", ptr[0]);

    if(munmap(ptr, sizeof buf)<0) abort();
    printf("3%c\n", ptr[0]); // Cause a segfault
}
```

With Address Sanitizer I get the following output:

```
1H
2H
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==8503==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x7fe7d0836000 (pc 0x55bda425c055 bp 0x7ffda5887210 sp 0x7ffda5887140 T0)
==8503==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
    #0 0x55bda425c054 in main /tmp/test/test1.c:22
    #1 0x7fe7cf64fb96 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #2 0x55bda425bcd9 in _start (/tmp/test/test1+0xcd9)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV /tmp/test/test1.c:22 in main
```

And here's the relevant part of output with Valgrind:

```
1H
2H
==8863== Invalid read of size 1
==8863==    at 0x108940: main (test1.c:22)
==8863==  Address 0x4029000 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==8863== 
==8863== 
==8863== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==8863==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x4029000
==8863==    at 0x108940: main (test1.c:22)
```

Compare this with the case when a `malloc`ed region is accessed after `free`. Test program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main()
{
    const char buf[]="Hello";
    char*const volatile ptr=malloc(sizeof buf);
    if(!ptr)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed");
        return 1;
    }
    memcpy(ptr,buf,sizeof buf);
    printf("1%c\n", ptr[0]);
    free(ptr);
    printf("2%c\n", ptr[0]); // Cause a segfault
}
```

Output with Address Sanitizer:

```
1H
=================================================================
==7057==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x602000000010 at pc 0x55b8f96b5003 bp 0x7ffff5179b70 sp 0x7ffff5179b60
READ of size 1 at 0x602000000010 thread T0
    #0 0x55b8f96b5002 in main /tmp/test/test1.c:17
    #1 0x7f4298fd8b96 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #2 0x55b8f96b4c49 in _start (/tmp/test/test1+0xc49)

0x602000000010 is located 0 bytes inside of 6-byte region [0x602000000010,0x602000000016)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f42994b3b4f in free (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10bb4f)
    #1 0x55b8f96b4fca in main /tmp/test/test1.c:16
    #2 0x7f4298fd8b96 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)

previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f42994b3f48 in __interceptor_malloc (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10bf48)
    #1 0x55b8f96b4e25 in main /tmp/test/test1.c:8
    #2 0x7f4298fd8b96 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
```

Output with Valgrind:

```
1H
==6888== Invalid read of size 1
==6888==    at 0x108845: main (test1.c:17)
==6888==  Address 0x522d040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 6 free'd
==6888==    at 0x4C30D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6888==    by 0x108840: main (test1.c:16)
==6888==  Block was alloc'd at
==6888==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6888==    by 0x1087D2: main (test1.c:8)
```

**My question**: is there any way to make Valgrind or a Sanitizer, or some other Linux-compatible tool output useful diagnostic about the context of access to `munmap`ped region (like where it had been `mmap`ped and `munmap`ped), similar to the above given output for the access-after-`free`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does valgrind memcheck support checking mmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334191/does-valgrind-memcheck-support-checking-mmap)

Comment: What part of **"Access not within mapped region at address 0x4029000  at 0x108940: main (test1.c:22)"** is a problem?  Valgrind is telling you your access is to memory not mapped by ptr[] at that point in the execution.  Means you are either outside the mapped region, or the region isn't there anymore.

Comment: @JohnH the problem is the lack of "This address has formerly been mapped by a syscall called with backtrace XYZ and unmapped by a syscall called with backtrace ABC", as is done for use-after-free errors.

Comment: @Ruslan mmap() maps a resource to a memory address, and the OS implementation doesn't even necessarily do any 'allocation' in the normal sense, just special address translation mapping to a resource.  It may or may not have done that; the C ABI doesn't require it.  An implementation literally could just be translating the calls directly to disk io. Valgrind's memcheck engine is a heap leak detection tool; mmap may not be using the heap at all in a given C library implementation.

Comment: @JohnH valgrind is a _memory error checker_. It definitely can diagnose a class of _invalid accesses_, not merely leaks. And being a CPU emulator, it definitely could make note of `mmap` system calls along with their parameters (address and length) and return values (actual address) to provide diagnostics on use-after-unmap. Anyway, the OP doesn't fix on Valgrind: it does mention that _"some other Linux-compatible tool"_ is acceptable too, if those I tried don't have this functionality.

Comment: @Ruslan You should read more carefully.  For example, for stack overrun errors, you can't use valgrind's default memcheck tools because it is a heap tool.  You have to use the experimental "exp-sgcheck" engine for that.  Read the docs on the various engines; memcheck, cachegrind, callgrind, helgrind, drd, massif, dhat, lackey, none, exp-sgcheck, exp-bbv, etc.  The docs for memcheck tell you what is can detect.  Note that, as I ponted out, there may be NO allocations on mmap, just address translation.  So, maybe not the core mission for memcheck's stated purpose in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

valgrind (and I guess asan does the same) can output a 'use after free' error
because it maintains a list of 'recently freed' blocks.
Such blocks are logically freed, but they are not returned (directly) to
the usable memory for further malloc calls.  instead they are marked unaddressable.
The size of this 'recently freed' block list can be tuned using

```
--freelist-vol=<number>          volume of freed blocks queue     [20000000]
--freelist-big-blocks=<number>   releases first blocks with size>= [1000000]
```

It would be possible to use a similar technique for munmap-ed memory:
rather than physically unmap it, it could be kept in a list of recently
unmapped blocks, be logically unmapped, but marked unaddressable.

Note that you could simulate that in your program by having a function
my_unmap that does not really do the unmap, but rather use the client requests
of valgrind to mark this memory as unaddressable.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Also note that freed lists are only tracked for malloc/free family (not mmap/munmap as in OPs question).

Comment: @yugr: effectively, I explicitly indicates that free list is done for malloc/free.  Otherwise, I answer to the question: "is this possible?". The answer is no, but it could be implemented and/or simulated.  If you think this does not answer to the question or seems to wrongly indicate that valgrind maintains a unmap-ped free list, can you give more precision about where the answer is not clear ? Thanks

Comment: Simply marking memory as unaddressable won't add much in OP's situation (his program _already_ segfaults on non-addressable memory). He's interested in "useful diagnostic about the context of access to munmapped region (like where it had been mmapped and munmapped)" like the one he gets from Asan. It's more or less obvious how to implement mmap tracking (with backtrace collection) from scratch but it's a non-trivial work so I suspect he is more interested in existing solutions.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way to make Valgrind or a Sanitizer, or some other Linux-compatible tool output useful diagnostic

I know of no such tool, although it would be relatively easy to make one.

Your problem is sufficiently different from heap corruption problems which *require* specialized tools, and probably doesn't need such a tool.

The major difference is the "action at a distance" aspect: with heap corruption, the code in which the problem manifests is often very far removed from the code in which the problem originates. Hence the need to track memory state, to have red zones, etc.

In your case, the access to `munmap`ped memory results in *immediate* crash. So if you just log every `mmap` and `munmap` that your program performs, you'll only have to look back for the last `munmap` that "covered" the address on which you crashed.

In addition, most programs perform relatively few `mmap` and `munmap` operations. If your program performs so many that you can't log them all, it's likely that it shouldn't actually do that (`mmap` and `munmap` are relatively *very* expensive system calls).